# Intersection of a line with a Sine function

Tags: trigonometry

A sine function is given as $f(x) = 40 + 25.\sin(\pi(x-1.5))$ domain $[0,6]$. I am asked to find a solution for $f(x) < 30$. I know that this is easily solvable with a solver such as in Excel but I want to do it using Algebra\Trigonometry. I did the following:

$$
30 = 40 + 25. \sin(\pi(x-1.5)) \\
\sin(\pi(x-1.5)) = -2/5 \\
(\pi(x-1.5)) = \sin^{-1} (-2/5) \\
(x-1.5) = 1/\pi[\pm\sin^{-1}(-2/5)] \\
x = 1.5+1/\pi[\pm\sin^{-1}(-2/5) + 2\pi n] \\
x = 1.5 + [\pm1/\pi.\sin^{-1}(-2/5)] + 2n \\
$$

I now make a table for $n = 0$ to $n = 6$ and calculate the $x$ values. The "$n$" value is used twice to account for the $\pm\sin$ values. The correct results are $0.63$, $1.37$, $2.63$, $3.37$, $4.63$, $5.37$. The equation gives the correct values for $1.37$, $3.37$, $5.37$ which are on the $+$ side of the equation. On the $-$ side I get $1.63$, $3.63$, $5.63$, $7.63$ which are incorrect. I have doubled and triple checked but cannot find the error! Please help.

Comment: Why did you introduce a $\pm$?

Comment: Because of its periodicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$30 = 40 + 25  \cdot \sin(π(x-1.5))$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \sin(π(x-1.5))= \frac{-2}{5} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow π(x-1.5) = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{5}\right)(-1)^n+\pi n ~~~ n \in Z$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x-1.5 = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{5}\right)(-1)^n+\pi n \right) $$

$$ \therefore x = 1.5 + \frac{1}{\pi} \left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{-2}{5}\right)(-1)^n+\pi n \right) $$

I have used the general formula for $\sin(x)$

This should give you your desired answers by letting $n = 0,1,2,...$

Comment: Thanks for replying, this solves the problem. The period is 2 so why πn instead of 2n at the end?

Comment: If you find this answer helpful , please consider 'ticking' it and voting it.                          The general formula for $\sin$ is if $\sin (\theta) = \sin(\alpha)$ then $\theta = n \pi + (-1)^n \alpha$

Comment: Sorry for going on but isn't sin(Θ) = sin(Θ+2π)?